# Make child height larger than parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure if I'm thinking of this the entirely wrong way but some guidance would be much appreciated. I'm essentially trying to get a child div larger than it's parent.

Please see image for what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

However the height on the container element will be smaller. Am I right in thinking I should have them as separate elements or is there a better practice way?

Comment: I would create a container Element, make it `position:relative` then make the others `position:absolute` in CSS and set the `top:` and `left:` properties of the Elements within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `position` and achieve what you want. I would say, a combination of `position`, negative `margin` will do the trick:

```css
.parent {background-color: #000; height: 100px;}
.parent .child {height: 200px; background-color: #ccc; width: 75%; margin: auto;}

.parent {margin-top: 100px;}
.parent .child {position: relative; top: -50%;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

If you don't know the height of the content, you can use `translate` to fix it to the centring:

```css
.parent {background-color: #000; width: 75%; margin: auto;}
.parent .child {height: 200px; background-color: #fff; width: 75%; margin: auto;}

.parent {margin-top: 100px; position: relative; min-height: 100px;}
.parent .child {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; right: 0; transform: translateY(-50%);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply `transform: scale(1.2);` your child element

```css
#parent{
  margin: 40px;
  background:#000;
}
#child{
  background:#d8d8d8;
  height:140px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:60%;
  transform:scale(1.2); -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```